# passing information from ruby into js script tags

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have an Rails app that,  after checking whether the user visiting a user's profile page is a current user (using ruby code), calls a JavaScript method based on the result of the conditional logic, as you see below.

Is there a way to pass the name of the user (available in the ruby code at <%= @user.name %> ) into the script tags, so that I could also pass it into the javascript function being called (in addition to the other parameter i pass).

**/views/users/show.html.erb**

```
<% if current_user?(@user) %> #@user represents the user who's profile page is being visited

        <script type='text/javascript'> 
        $(document).ready(function() {     #I want to get <%= @user.name %> inside here
          var currentuser = true; 
        app.views.user_view.compTemplates(currentuser)});
       </script>

<% else %>

   ...code ommitted...

<% end %>
```

Update:

Following the suggestion of the first answer to this question, I did this inside the script tags.

```
   var currentusername =  <%=  @user.name %>;
```

However, once <%= @user.name %> evaluates (to 'Veronica', in this example), Veronica is appearing for the first time in the js code and is now registering an error 'Veronica is undefined'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inline Ruby has to go inside #{} tags.

```
var currentusername =  '#{ <%= @user.name %> }';
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for this: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-escape_javascript

Example given:

```
$('some_element').replaceWith('<%=j render 'some/element_template' %>');
```

or

```
$('some_element').replaceWith('<%= escape_javascript render 'some/element_template' %>');
```

For your particular example you can also do: (I don't think the `to_json` is required)

```
<script type='text/javascript'> 
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var currentuser = true;
    var userName = <%= @user.name.to_json %>;
  app.views.user_view.compTemplates(currentuser)});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried what you did, and passed it in as a parameter to the compTemplates method--compTemplates(currentuser, userName)--but thwne I do consolelog(userName) in the view that receives it, it says the user name (i.e. the actual user name that's been computed, not the variable userName) 'is not defined'. Could you explain why?

Comment: can you confirm that the @user does have a name? (`print @user.inspect`) Perhaps in the template (not the script part)? Also, did you try `escape_javascript`? Can you inspect the object? `alert(JSON.stringify(userName))`. We're trying to find where it's failing.

Comment: I do this  var currentusername = <%=  @user.name %>; in the show.html.erb page, and it's saying 'Veronica' (the @user.name) is undefined in the javascript console.

Comment: I also did <%= escape_javascript @user.name %> but same problem. The JSON.stringify(userName) variable (after I assign it) does nothing

Comment: I know. Once <%= @user.name %> is evaluated, the computed name (Veronica) is appearing for the first time in the js code, and it hasn't been previously defined, so 'Veronica' is 'undefined'